# Multiple GET requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

I'm developing an application, and on one page it requires approximately 12-15 GET requests to be made to an API in the background. My original intent was to make the requests using AJAX from jQuery, but it turns out that it is impossible to do so with the Steam Web API I am using.

Doing this in the Rails controller before the page loads is, for obvious reasons, very slow.

After I get the data from the API, I parse it and send it to the JavaScript using gon. The problem is that I don't know how to get and set the data *after* the page renders.

Here is what my controller would look like:

```
def index
  @title = "My Stats"
  if not session.key?(:current_user) then
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    gon.watch.winlossdata = GetMatchHistoryRawData(session[:current_user][:uid32])
  end
end
```

The function `GetMatchHistoryRawData` is a helper function that is calling the GET requests.

Comment: Why not make the ajax requests to your controller instead of directly to the steam api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the whenever gem --(possibly, see below)....

Set a value in a queue database table before rendering the page. Using a "cron" task (whenever gem) that monitors the queue table you can make requests to the Steam API and populate a queue result table. On the rendered page you could implement a JavaScript periodic check with AJAX to monitor the queue result table and populate the page once the API returns a result.

Additional Info:

I have not used the whenever gem yet but I did some more reading on it and there might be an issue with the interval not being short enough to make it as close to real time as possible. I am currently doing my job processing with a Java application implementing a timer but have wondered about moving to whenever and CRON. So whenever might not work for you but the idea of an asynchronous processor doing the work of contacting the API is the gist of my answer. If the payload from the Steam API is small and returned fast enough then like what was stated above you could use a direct call via AJAX to the controller and then the Steam API.

Regarding the Rails code it should be pretty much standard.

controller:

```
def index
  # Create a Steam API Queue row in the database and save any pertinent information needed for contacting the Steam API
  @unique_id = Model.id  # some unique id created for the Steam API queue row
end

# AJAX calls START
def get_api_result
  # Check for a result using 
  params[:unique_id]
  # render partial for <div>
end
# AJAX calls end
```

View: index

```
# Display your page     
# Setup an intermittent AJAX call to "controller#get_api_result" with some unique id #{@unique_id} i.e. params[:unique_id] to identify the Steam API Queue table row, populate the result of the call into a <div>
```

external_processor_code (Whenever Gem, Java implementation, some Job processor, etc...)

Multiple threads should be available to process the Steam API Queue table and retrieve results every few seconds and populate the result table that will be read by the controller when requested via the AJAX call.

To give a complete example of this type of implementation would take some time so I have briefly, from the conceptual level, outlined it above. There might be some other ways to do this that could be more efficient with the way technology is expanding so please do some investigation.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this would work? This sounds like the perfect solution.